# Blender Video Editor: How to move a picture or movie from place a to place b and capture the movement into the video?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, video

Let's say I want to move a picture in the Video Editor from place a to b, over 100 frames. A way to do this is to create 100 pictures and adjust the coordinates of each one in each frame. It's gonna take forever! and 100 frames are very few! Can I automate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, keyframes will allow you can automate your goal.

Select regular strip.
Add a Menu/Effect Strip/Transform strip to a regular video/image strip.
Select new transform strip.

Keyframe the position.  Frame 1.

[image]

In the image above the mouse was used the to get the [Insert Keyframe] menu option.

Next a second keyframe on frame 100.  Yellow indicates key frame.

[image]

Next Blender places the images on frames 2-99 via interpolation.

[image]

There are tutorial resources here a blender.stackexchange and other video websites.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcInAv9iHmU&index=15&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS